# Find the complete integral (CI) of: $z^2\left(p^2+q^2\right)=x^2+y^2$

Tags: calculus, partial-differential-equations

I recently encountered this question:

> Solve by Charpit's method (find Complete Integral or CI): $z^2\left(p^2+q^2\right)=x^2+y^2$

I tried writing down the Charpit's auxillary equations as follows:

$$\frac{dx}{2pz^2}=\frac{dy}{2qz^2}=\frac{dz}{2z^2\left(p^2+q^2\right)}=-\frac{dp}{2x-p\left(p^2+q^2\right)}=-\frac{dq}{2y-q\left(p^2+q^2\right)}$$

However, I couldn't find any two equations (or generate new using multipliers) that would enable me to find $p$ and $q$ in terms of $x,y,z$. I absolutely have no idea how to proceed at this step.

Would someone please help me to solve this?

PS : Here $p = \frac{\partial z}{\partial x}$ and $q = \frac{\partial z}{\partial y}$

Comment: This is not a linear first order PDE. So why do you think that having "two equations" would help ? Why do you need the CI ? What is exactly the wording of the problem ? Is there no boundary condition ?

Comment: There are no boundary conditions given, we need to find the CI in the form $ z=f(x,y) $ in terms of two arbitrary constants....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your equation
\begin{align}
z^2(z_x^2+z_y^2)=x^2+y^2,
\end{align}
I’ll take $z=\sqrt{2^{1/2}u(x,y)}$ so that
\begin{align}
u_x^2-x^2=-u_y^2+y^2.
\end{align}
This falls under the class of [separable first-order PDEs](http://home.iitj.ac.in/%7Ek.r.hiremath/teaching/Lecture-notes-PDEs/node13.html), therefore both sides of the equation are equal to some constant $c$:
\begin{align}
u_x=\sqrt{x^2-c},\quad u_y=\sqrt{y^2-c}.
\end{align}
Via the chain rule we see that
\begin{align}
\mathrm du&=u_x\mathrm dx+u_y\mathrm dy,\\
\mathrm du&=\sqrt{x^2+c}\mathrm dx+\sqrt{y^2-c}\mathrm dy.
\end{align}
Upon integration and substituting in for $z$ we have our complete integral
\begin{align}
2^{1/2}z^2=x\sqrt{x^2+c}+c\log\left(x+\sqrt{x^2+c}\right)+y\sqrt{y^2-c}-c\log\left(y+\sqrt{y^2-c}\right)+k,
\end{align}

with $k$ being our second constant. Note that there are four cases corresponding to whether you take plus or minus when taking square roots, it would just be a mess if I wrote it all in!

Comment: Thank you for the answer!